# How to add QSlider to toolbar in mainwindow using pyqt5 in python

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm now using PyQt5 in python to develop a GUI for my program. I have added some QAction to the toolbar, like start, pause and stop icon. However, I don't know how to add a QSlider to the toolbar in my mainwindow. I prefer to add the QSlider to the position which is marked by a red rectangle. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QToolBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html) has the [addWidget()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html#addWidget) method that allows you to add widgets:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        toolbar = self.addToolBar("toolbar")
        toolbar.addAction("start")
        toolbar.addAction("pause")
        toolbar.addAction("stop")
        self.slider = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        toolbar.addWidget(self.slider)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: cool! It does work for me. But how can I adjust the size of this slider? I mean it's too long for me. I have tried toolbar.setGeometry function, but it doesn't work. Another question, do you know what does the function toolbar.SetFoucusPolicy do? Thanks for your kind help

Comment: @JiaweiLu if you want to set a fixed width you can use `setFixedWitdh()`, for example `self.slider.setFixedWidth(100)`, On the other hand, SetFocusPolicy establishes the policy of how the focus gets a widget, for example by pressing the widget, with the TAB key, etc. read http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop. On the other hand if my answer does not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it then review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.

Comment: A question arises, could we use alignment such as `toolbar.addWidget(self.slider, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)`. I do not think so that would work simply. Could this `slider` aligns to left or center?