# Adding a slider to pyQT menu

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I am new to PyQT. I want to add a slider to a menuBar, but menuBar does not have an option to add a Widget. I can see examples where slider is added to toolbar using **addWidget** like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53245066/how-to-add-qslider-to-toolbar-in-mainwindow-using-pyqt5-in-python)

Comment: See [`setCornerWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html#setCornerWidget).

Comment: Thanks, I want to have this slider come as a menu option rather than on the right corner. I found out that, QWidgetAction can be used for this.

Comment: Ok, consider that there are some issues with using QWidgetAction in a menu bar, and you also probably need to disable the native menubar that is used on some systems (macOS and some Linux distributions).